# An orthogonal matrix has eigenvalue $1$ with the eigenspace $E(1)$ of dimension $n-1$. Then $-1$ is also an eigenvalue with $E(-1)$ of dimension $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space ($g$ scalar product) and let $f:V \to V$ such that $g(f(u), f(v)) = g(u,v)$. It is known that the matrix associated to $f$ with respect to an orthogonal basis is orthogonal, and that the only eigenvalues of $f$ can be $1$ or $-1$.

Now, suppose that $f$ has as eigenvalue $1$ with the eigenspace $E(1)$ of dimension $n-1$. How do I prove that then $-1$ is also an eigenvalue with $E(-1)$ of dimension $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume henceforth that $V$ is over the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise it is not true that the only eigenvalues of an orthogonal transformation are $\pm 1$.

Take a non-zero vector $u$ orthogonal to $E(1)$, then the span of $u$ is the $1$-dimensional orthogonal complement of $E(1)$. Pick any $v\in E(1)$. Since $$0=g(u,v)=g(f(u),f(v))=g(f(u),v),$$ we deduce that $f(u)$
is orthogonal to $E(1)$. So $f(u)=\lambda u$ for some $\lambda$, and we must
have $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$. (It is here where we use the fact that $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{R}$. In the complex case we could only deduce that $|\lambda|=1$ ) Now, we can't have $\lambda=1$ because all vectors with eigen-value $1$ are in $E(1)$ and $u$ is not. Therefore $\lambda=-1$ and we get the result that the orthogonal complement of $E(1)$ is the $1$-dimensional subspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=-1$.

Comment: Very well done; thanks!

Comment: May I ask you if you'd like to have a look at this question too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421679/rigorous-definition-of-oriented-line-in-an-euclidean-affine-space